# How can I load an unnamed function in Lua?

Tags: lua

I want users of my C++ application to be able to provide anonymous functions to perform small chunks of work.

Small fragments like this would be ideal.

```
function(arg) return arg*5 end
```

Now I'd like to be able to write something as simple as this for my C code,

```
// Push the function onto the lua stack
lua_xxx(L, "function(arg) return arg*5 end" )
// Store it away for later
int reg_index = luaL_ref(L, LUA_REGISTRY_INDEX);
```

However I dont think lua_loadstring will do "the right thing".

Am I left with what feels to me like a horrible hack?

```
void push_lua_function_from_string( lua_State * L, std::string code )
{
   // Wrap our string so that we can get something useful for luaL_loadstring
   std::string wrapped_code = "return "+code;
   luaL_loadstring(L, wrapped_code.c_str());
   lua_pcall( L, 0, 1, 0 );
}

push_lua_function_from_string(L, "function(arg) return arg*5 end" );
int reg_index = luaL_ref(L, LUA_REGISTRY_INDEX);
```

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need access to parameters, the way you have written is correct. `lua_loadstring` returns a function that represents the chunk/code you are compiling. If you want to actually get a function back from the code, you have to `return` it. I also do this (in Lua) for little "expression evaluators", and I don't consider it a "horrible hack" :)

If you only need some callbacks, without any parameters, you can directly write the code and use the function returned by `lua_tostring`. You can even pass parameters to this chunk, it will be accessible as the `...` expression. Then you can get the parameters as:

```
local arg1, arg2 = ...
-- rest of code
```

You decide what is better for you - "ugly code" inside your library codebase, or "ugly code" in your Lua functions.

Comment: I've also decided its not quite as hacky as my gut feel suggested. And since end users are going to be writing the lua functions, I think that my "not-so-horrible" hack is the only way to go.

Comment: Michal has it right. The "chunk" can accept arguments but needs the return.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at my [ae](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/#ae). It caches functions from expressions so you can simply say `ae_eval("a*x^2+b*x+c")` and it'll only compile it once.